# How to periodically run a script inside a fresh Docker container on Amazon AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Docker image for a web app which needs a specific script to be run once a day. The web app is going to be deployed to a web tier in Elastic Beanstalk. What would be the best way to create a container for this image in order to run the script and then remove this container?

Ideally, I'd like to have some easy way to do the following every 24 hours: Create a worker environment in Elastic Beanstalk with a new Docker container, run the script and remove the worker environment. But this doesn't seem possible.

I've found a few services in AWS that might help (Simple Workflow, OpsWorks, Data Pipeline), but seem massively complicated for what I want.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what about using cron jobs as described at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingcookbook-extend-cron.html

Comment: Thanks! Just to clarify: Are you suggesting to create an OpsWorks-based cron job to create an EC2 instance running Docker, run my script and then terminate the EC2 instance? If so, isn't there anything easier that I could try?

Comment: sorry I'm not experienced enough with it to go into details